# Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ has an even norm, then $\sqrt{2} \mid n$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Aside from multiplying and dividing some specific numbers in this ring, e.g., $(1 + \sqrt{2})\sqrt{2}$ I have not really done anything productive on this question. I either go around in circles or jump to conclusions, such as that it follows from the fact that $\langle \sqrt{2} \rangle$ is a prime ideal with prime norm.

Though I do have this hunch that a very similar argument can be used to prove something similar in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$...

Comment: Have you tried simply dividing $n$ by $\sqrt{2}$ and seeing what is needed for it to belong to the ring?

Comment: After Mr. Watson's answer, I did try that. But I'm not sure how to take it over to other $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ (with $d$ even), such as for example, with $2 + \sqrt{6}$.

Comment: But your question only refers to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$?  (Well, also $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$, but it carries over very easily to that domain.)  What is the precise statement you are trying to carry over to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$?  It's not clear what you want "even" and "$\sqrt{2}$" to correspond to for general $d$.

Comment: My question mentioned $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ from the start. But as I think more about it, I also want to figure it out for divisors of $2$ in other domains, and I alluded to that in the bounty statement.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{2}$ is not an element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ in general...

Comment: That's right, which is why in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ I'm looking at $2 + \sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36440/discussion-between-erick-wong-and-mr-brooks).

Comment: @Mr. Brooks : I tried to add some details to my previous answer.

Comment: @Watson : Thank you very much. I wanted to award you the bounty but it says I have to wait 40 minutes. I'll be off to dinner then, so maybe tomorrow.

Comment: @ErickWong As I thought more about it, maybe what I'm getting at now is different from the question I originally posted and maybe therefore it needs to be a separate question: if $2$ is irreducible and prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, does it divide all numbers of even norm? Or if it splits into primes, do those primes divide all numbers of even norm?

Comment: @Mr.Brooks : suppose that $2$ is prime in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$ (in particular it is irreducible), and $x=a+b\sqrt d$ has even norm, so that $2 \mid a^2-db^2 = (a+b\sqrt d)(a-b \sqrt d)$. As $2$ is prime, you get $2 \mid x$ or $2 \mid x' = a-b \sqrt d$. In the first case, we are done. In the second one, $a-b \sqrt d = 2(r+s\sqrt d)$ for some integers $r,s$. In particular $b=-2s$, so that $x=a+b\sqrt d = 2(r-s\sqrt d)$ is divisible by $2$ in $\Bbb Z [\sqrt d]$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the norm $N(a+b\sqrt 2)=a^2-2b^2$ is even, then $a^2$ is even, and so is $a$. Then $a=2a'$ for some integer $a'$. Therefore :

> $$a+b\sqrt 2 = 2a'+b\sqrt 2=\sqrt 2 (b+a'\sqrt 2)$$ From this you conclude that $\sqrt 2 \mid a+b\sqrt 2$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$, provided that the norm of $a+b\sqrt 2$ is even.

---

More generally, if $d \in \Bbb Z$ is [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), and if $d \mid N(a+b\sqrt d)$ (in $\Bbb Z$), then $\sqrt d \mid a+b\sqrt d$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

Indeed, if $N(a+b\sqrt d)= a^2-db^2$ is a multiple of $d$, then $a^2$ is a multiple of $d$. As $d$ is square-free, you have that $d \mid a$ (this is not true in general, for instance $d=2 \cdot 4^2=32$ divides $a^2=64=8^2$, but $32$ doesn't divide $a=8$).

Then you can write $a=da'$ for some integer $a'$. Therefore $$a+b\sqrt d = \sqrt d (a'\sqrt d + b)$$ is a multiple of $\sqrt d$ as desired.

---

The converse also holds (if $d$ is square-free). Suppose that $x=a+b\sqrt d$ is a multiple of $\sqrt d$ (in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$).
Then you can write $$a+b\sqrt d = \sqrt d(m+n\sqrt d)=nd+m\sqrt d$$
for some integers $m$ and $n$.

The norm of $x$ is
$$N(x)=N(nd+m\sqrt d)=n^2 d^2 - dm^2=d(dn^2-m^2).$$
In particular the norm is a multiple of $d$.

---

Here is an example. Let $d=6$ and $x=2+\sqrt 6$.
The norm of $x$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 6]$ is $N(2+\sqrt 6)=4-6=-2$ which is not a multiple of $d=6$. In particular, $x$ is not a multiple of $\sqrt 6$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 6]$.

It is possible to prove this without using norms.
Indeed, suppose that we could write
$$x=2+\sqrt 6 = \sqrt 6(m+n\sqrt 6) = 6n + m\sqrt 6 \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt 6]$$
for some integers $m$ and $n$.

Then recall that if $a+b\sqrt d = 0$ then $a=b=0$ (where $d$ is square-free). Suppose for a contradiction that $b≠0$. Then $\sqrt d =-a/b$ would be rational, which is impossible. Then $b=0$, and $a=0$.

In particular, $2+\sqrt 6 = 6n + m\sqrt 6$ is equivalent to $2-6n+\sqrt 6 (1-m)=0$. This yields $2-6n=0$ and $1-m=0$. But $3$ divides the integer $6n$ and $6n=2$... this is not possible.

Hence, we proved that $x=2+\sqrt 6$ is not a multiple of $\sqrt 6$ in $\Bbb Z [\sqrt 6]$.

(Notice that saying "$\sqrt d$ is irrational" is equivalent to saying $N(a+b\sqrt d)=0 \iff a=b=0$).

Comment: Hence we proved it because the truth is the opposite, $2 + \sqrt{6}$ is a divisor of $\sqrt{6}$. But the OP will realize, if he hasn't already, why everyone thought he was more interested in $\langle n \rangle \subset \langle \sqrt{d} \rangle$ than in $\langle n \rangle \subset \langle p \rangle$ where $\langle 2 \rangle \subseteq \langle p \rangle$.